# Python Requests - getting list of usable methods/URIs?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I need to check how to make integration with one system, but there is no documentation. The only thing I got, is an URL and user/password and that it uses restful.

Is there a way to simply get list of methods/URIs with needed parameters that can be used in that system?

I mean is python requests have some methods that would search for such thing?

for example I have this:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('user', 'pass')
r = s.get('https://url.com/', verify=True)
```

I tried to use `r.__dict__`, but didn't find much with that.

Comment: Does the API provide a WADL?

Comment: I guess not, but don't know for sure. How can I find out?

Comment: Is https://url.com the real URL?

Comment: No, it was just an example

Comment: So please provide the real URL or at least as much information you can give about it. It is impossible to disover a REST API without any further information.

Comment: Well maybe you can tell me some specific information that would be useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70693/discussion-between-lutz-horn-and-andrius).

Answer (score 0):

You need a web spider. Try [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Comment: That would only help if there are links on the index page. The question indicates that there are none.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of how to search for URI with scrappy?

Comment: @LutzHorn If there are none, there are none.

Comment: @Andrius Maybe you could check out the example shown on the home page.

Comment: Yes, but if there are no links, this does not mean that there is no REST API.

Comment: @LutzHorn This is not a philosophy salon. If you have any advice helpful, shoot it yourself.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the REST angle of the question. Scraping a HTML page is not the same as discovering a REST API. I am trying to talk to you about why I think your answer is not useful. Do you understand my point?

Comment: @LutzHorn Your point is one thing you cannot see doesn't mean it doesn't exist. The poster just wanted to yank out a restful url list in a simplest way. So I suggest him the crawl over the site and see anything meaningful. Since "The only thing I got, is an URL and user/password and that it uses restful" I suppose there are nothing else to do except this.